# $\sum_i \sin x_i$ diverges implies $\sum_i x_i$ diverges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

If the series $\sum_i \sin x_i$ diverges does $\sum_i x_i$ necessarily diverge?

I feel like this should be a simple series comparison test or something, but I cannot figure a proof out. If you could point me to a duplicate that would also be helpful (can't find anything...)
Thanks.

**Edit:** If it makes it easier, we can suppose that $x_i > 0$.

Comment: Are the $x_i$ positive?

Comment: Let's assume that they are.

Comment: If we remove the restriction that $x_i >0$, the problem seems non-trivial to me (or maybe I'm just rusty in the morning!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sin(x)$ $\le$ $x$:

Theorem: If $f$ is a continuous function on the closed interval $[a,b]$ and differentiable on the open interval $(a,b)$ then there exists a number $c∈(a,b)$ such that $f′(c)=\frac{f(b)−f(a)}{b−a}$.

C1: Suppose that $x=0$. Then, $0=\sin(0)$ $\le$ $x=0$

C2: Suppose that $0 \lt x\lt 1$. Let $f(t)=\sin(t)$. Then $f$ is continuous and differentiable everywhere. In particular, $f$ is continuous on $[0,x]$ and differentiable on $(0,x)$. By the Mean Value theorem there exists number $c∈(0,1)$ such that:

$f′(c)=\frac{f(x)−f(0)}{x−0}$

The derivative of $\sin x$ is $\cos x$. Therefore:

$\cos(c)=\frac{\sin(x)−\sin(0)}x$

$\cos(c)= \frac{\sin(x)}{x}$

Note that the cosine function is bounded, that is, $−1≤cos(t)≤1$ for every real number t. Therefore:
$−1≤\frac{\sin x}x≤1⇒\frac{\sin x}x≤1$

Since $0<x<1$, we multiply both sides of the inequality above to get that $sinx≤x$.

C3: Suppose that $1≤x<∞$. We know that $sin(t)$ is a bounded function and $−1≤\sin(t)≤1$ for every real number $t$. Thus $\sin x≤1≤x$, i.e., $\sin x≤x$.

As such, $sin(x)$ $\le$ $x$ for any $x∈R$.

Then,

$\sum_{i}  \sin x_i$ ≤ $\sum_{i} x_i$, because any element of the first sum will be smaller or equal to the corresponding element of the second sum, because $\sin(x)$ $\le$ $x$ for any $x∈R$.

If $\sum_{i}  \sin x_i$  diverges and $\sum_{i}  \sin x_i$ ≤ $\sum_{i} x_i$, that means:
$\sum_{i} x_i$ must diverge as well.

Answer (score 0):

If the $x_i$s are nonnegative and tend to $0$, the series $\sum \sin x_i$ and $\sum x_i$ have *asymptotically equivalent* general terms. In this case, a  theorem from asymptotic analysis asserts that they both converge or they both diverge.

Comment: Ithink so – I learnt as a first year student. See [Limit comparison test] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test) on Wikipedia.